# NODEJS SMB2 - convert buffer to date and time

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, buffer, smb

I'm using this package for connecting to shared directory([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@marsaud/smb2)). Fork from original smb2.

I'm trying to change directory readdir function (now only returns filenames). 
So I looked what samba returns I all I can get "parsed" is this:

```
{ Index: 0,
    CreationTime: <Buffer 05 6f bd 13 76 ba d1 01>,
    LastAccessTime: <Buffer 05 6f bd 13 76 ba d1 01>,
    LastWriteTime: <Buffer b8 e4 a8 09 c0 9f d1 01>,
    ChangeTime: <Buffer 3e bd 43 17 c1 bc d1 01>,
    EndofFile: <Buffer 57 12 00 00 00 00 00 00>,
    AllocationSize: <Buffer 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00>,
    FileAttributes: 32,
    FilenameLength: 16,
    EASize: 0,
    ShortNameLength: 0,
    FileId: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>,
    Filename: 'test.xxx' } ]
```

I can recognize files and directories by FileAttributes. But I need to get CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime.

From structure of the buffer I can recognize that only thing that I need to do, is convert that buffers into date/time.

So I tried almost everything. Convert to **utf**, **ucs2**, **readUInt32LE(0)**, **readUInt32BE(0)**. I find [this](https://github.com/dvenrao/SMB/blob/master/SMB2/smb2pack/commands/query_directory.py#L27)(python implementation) that this timestamps are in little endian as **unsingned long long** (I do not use python often but I think ***<Q*** that means). But in nodejs there is no such type.

I parse one file information like this github.com/marsaud/node-smb2/blob/master/lib/messages/query_directory.js#L61

***Edit:**
So I tried @gnerkus solution but It would not work. Returns this

```
-4.377115596215621e-89 //readDoubleBE()
Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time) //Date()
```

And for some buffers It returns Invalid date.

Si I checked length buffer as **Buffer.byteLength(obj.CreationTime)** and it returns *8*. It's obvious that buffer has length of 8. So I tried using function *readUInt8()* that returns following

```
6.618094934489594e-300 //readUInt8()
Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)  //Date()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after long search on microsoft msd and npm. I find that buffer is 64bites length(8bytes). It consist of 2 dwords. The meaning of the unbuffered integer is FILETIME timestamp.

So if I wanted to parse creationTime from that buffer I needed to do this :

```
buffer = v.LastWriteTime;
var low = buffer.readUInt32LE(0);
var high = buffer.readUInt32LE(4);
v.LastWriteTime = FileTime.toDate({low: low, high: high}).toISOString()
```

I hope it would help someone. I used npm plugun ***win32filetime*** to convert FILETIME to javascript *Date Object*

Answer (score 1):

You can read the buffer with [buffer.readDoubleBE()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readdoublebe_offset_noassert):

```
// This assumes the name of the object returned by smb2 is 'obj'
var createdAt = new Date(obj.CreationTime.readDoubleBE());
```